# How to specific the Itemsource of carseview?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I made a carseView to display Image Banner like the blog.

```
<CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding Banner}">
            <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
```

and give the ItemSource like :

```
public ObservableCollection<ImageData> Banner ;
Banner = new ObservableCollection<ImageData>
            {
                new ImageData()
                {
                    ImageUrl = "b1.png",
                    ImageWidth = (int)App.UIWidth,
                    ImageHeight=(int)App.UIHeight
                },
                new ImageData()
                {
                    ImageUrl="b2.png",
                    ImageWidth=(int)App.UIWidth,
                    ImageHeight=(int)App.UIHeight

                }      
            };
```

I think it is right but it always go to an error:the specified cast is not valid.

I tried many solutions.The binding context is right without doubt.
please tell me where is the mistake.

my xamarin version:3.6.0.264807

Comment: first, Banner should be a public property with a getter.  Second, which specific line is throwing the exception?

Comment: @Jason Thank you Jason,I've added getter but it also crashed.In the main.cs line17

Comment: Main.cs:17 UIApplication.cs:63 UIApplication.cs:79 .ViewDidLoad () [0x00035] in <0648e2dffe9e4201b8c6e274ced6579f>:0

Comment: if you remove the data access code does that page load?  I suspect there is some other problem on that page causing the exception.

Comment: I created a new project only add depended code and it also case an exception,I remove the data it didi loadded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create simple demo about using CarouselView and I don't have any issue at my side.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage
x:Class="test2.Page15"
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
xmlns:forms="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <forms:CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding banners}">
            <forms:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Source="{Binding imageurl}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </forms:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        </forms:CarouselView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class Page15 : ContentPage
{
    public ObservableCollection<model11> banners { get; set; }
    public Page15 ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        banners = new ObservableCollection<model11>()
        {
            new model11(){imageurl="a11.jpg"},
            new model11(){imageurl="c1.jpg"},
            new model11(){imageurl="c2.jpg"},
            new model11(){imageurl="c3.jpg"}

        };
        this.BindingContext = this;
    }
}
public class model11
{
    public string imageurl { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: you are using the CarouselView.FormsPlugin. I've done of it .I mean the native xamarin.forms's control CarouselView not this plugin.But Thank you for your answer

Comment: @daotian,I modify my code and use Xamarin.forms.CarouseView control, but I also don't have any issue at my side, please see the code above, I have modified.

Comment: Thankyou I've no idea what is wrong with my program.but thank you.